# Bootstrap popover with clickevent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am in deep troubles with this mystery: I am using bootstrap 3.2 and my popovers won't show with click event.

After lots of testing I am falling short of ideas to find where the problem comes from.

**Here the code**: http://jsfiddle.net/drgsa8hr/3/ 
`(I added the same js files my project is using )`

If I read well: Popover extends Tooltip :https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/popover.js#L32

Test 1: Tooltip works with click & hover events

Test 2: Popover works with hover events

Test 3: Problem: Popover is not working with click event.

Would you have any idea to correct this?

Edit: my first post wasn't clear enough, sorry. This fiddle is working properly for me. However, the exact same code in my project isn't showing the popover with click event. I am looking for a solution to find why popover is working with hover and not with click event. Thank you again.

Comment: It's working for me and is implemented correctly

Comment: Thank you fellas for your tests :-) However, I am sorry I wasn't precise enough in my post. The fiddle works with me too, but it's in my project it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution: it was coming from a copy/pasted code of the jqueryAimMenu example.

https://rawgit.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim/master/example/example.html

```
$(document).click(function() {
        // Simply hide the submenu on any click. Again, this is just a hacked
        // together menu/submenu structure to show the use of jQuery-menu-aim.
        $(".popover").css("display", "none");
        $("a.maintainHover").removeClass("maintainHover");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your fiddle link, it is working well on my FF-32.0.3,Windows 8.

[image]

Comment: As for Christina and Vitorino, thank you for your test! I wasn't precise enough in the original post, the fiddle works with me too, but it's in my project it is not working.

Comment: Hi @Xavier13, Any type of error occurred in your project ? if any please send us your console log.

Comment: the sad thing is that it is not displaying any error. Bootstrap just won't show popover with click event.